# What compiler(s) can I use to link C++ with D?

Tags: d

I want to create a program with a mix of C++ and D, and I would like to be able to work on it as a single project.

My understanding is that I can use some D compiler to output *.obj files, then I can do the same with some C++ compiler, and then link all of the *.obj files into a single binary, is this correct?

If this is correct, can I use any C++ compiler with any D compiler? Or am I restricted to certain combinations like, DMD-DMC, LDC-Clang, and GDC-GCC?

Which linker do I use?

And which standard library do I use?

Comment: See also: http://dlang.org/cpp_interface.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In theory, you could mix the compilers, but in practice you'd have object file format and standard library mixing issues from time to time, especially on 32 bit Windows. It'd be hard there, but not too bad elsewhere since most things are based on de-facto standards like MSVC and gcc.

Win32: use dmc++ (the digital mars compiler and C runtime) with dmd OR g++ and gdc. Other combinations can be done but are messy. Best way to mix code in Win32 across compiler families is to build a DLL with a C or COM api and use that from D.

Win64: Since dmd uses the 64 bit Microsoft format and C library, you should have little trouble mixing dmd with Visual C++ code. I'm not sure about g++ on Windows64 with dmd.

Most other platforms, including Linux: dmd works along well with g++, as does gdc + gcc. I'm not sure if ldc and g++ are compatible, but ldc should work fine with other LLVM based commpilers on any platform too.

Comment: so far, a trivial add(int,int) function seems to work fine using clang and ldc2. Thanks!

Comment: More complex functions might give D runtime problems depending on where main is. If main is defined in D, it should all just work. If it is defined in C++ though, you'll need to initialize the D runtime before calling most D functions. http://dlang.org/phobos/core_runtime.html#initialize I've written about this at greater length before too so if you'd like to know more some searching on Runtime.initalize should turn something up (or just ask here and I'll come back to it)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I will have to look into this. I would like to eventually target Android, where a user defined native entry point is not possible. It sounds like Runtime.initialize() is something that would have to be called after the static initialization phase, but before any D code is executed. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: There's someone working on porting the runtime to android now. The runtime can be initialized at basically any time, you can do it from inside a regular D function too, you just need to do it before calling *certain* D functions like a GC memory allocation. The C subset of D works without the runtime at all.

Comment: What I was getting at though is whether I could just stick Runtime.initialize in a static ctor/dtor ;) Anyways, I tried a c++ main, and that seemed to work too. Creating a basic class and some calls to writeln() seemed to work, after linking d-runtime, phobos, and my object files using clang++.

Comment: oh yeah, you can't use a D static ctor because they are run by Runtime.initialize!